# Less intrusive alternative to Appsfire Deals?

Tags: ios, software-recommendation

I like the basic idea of [Appsfire Deals](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/appsfire-deals-free-daily/id418295945): tag applications you're interested in, get a push notification when they're offered with a discount. But I don't like that the app frequently notifies me of promotions for apps I did *not* tag. (I already turned off the “Daily Recommendations” in the app's push notification settings, the only other option offered there is to turn off push notifications completely.) Is there an alternative to Appsfire Deals which limits its push notifications to apps you're actually interested in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is for example [AppShopper](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/appshopper/id387037496?mt=8). To use the notification feature (called "wishlist") you have to create a free AppShopper account.

I'm using it for a while and don't get any spam.

Answer (score 1):

We understood your feedback about the notifications and Appfire Deals will offer additional configuration options very soon.

Note also that promoting apps helps us to finance our work. Our goal is to provide you the best experience for finding the greatest deals on the App Store.

Maxence

Appsfire

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's great to hear from the development team directly. I understand your need to finance your work, but I hope you'll introduce a less intrusive way to satisfy it. I usually go for the “pay to get rid of ads” option if apps offer one.